# Why is my bottom navigation assuming my activity height instead of my FragmentContainerView's?

Tags: android, kotlin

My bottom navigation fragments are assuming my activity height instead of my FragmentContainerView's. I would like to know what the cause might be.

This is my bottomNavigation activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/default_background"
    tools:context=".ui.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_tab"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_blank" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My interface is looking something like this, in this particularly case I have a marginBottom of 32dp, but as you can see the view is assuming my activity constraints.

[image]

(I'm sorry before I forgot the print)

I expect the result to be something like this, that is my preview screen. I want the bottom of my fragment to be the top of the BottomNavigationView:

[image]

I don't know what code can help finding the solution for this issue but I can provide more code if needed

Comment: This is because you are entering fragmentcontainerview in the activity.

Comment: You can support your question with images.

Comment: You might want to post an image of how your current layout looks, and what you think is wrong with it / what you expect it to look like. From that XML, your `BottomNavigationView` is inside your `Activity`, but its height is `wrap_content`. So that's unrelated to the `Activity` or the `FragmentContainerView` - it's as tall as it needs to be. The `FragmentContainerView`'s height is constrained to fit the remaining space between the top of the `Activity` and the top of the `BottomNavigationView`

Comment: I already edited my post, I'm sorry for the cut of context there. This last comment makes sense to me and it is exactly what I want to show in my interface, but my fragment is ignoring my FragmentContainerView bottom constraints, I don't know why.

Also what is wrong with having the fragmentcontainerview in the activity? (I'm referring to the first comment)

Comment: Ok, already solved the issue. I had 2 different activity_main files, and one of the files had a small bug in the xml. I don't know how that second activity was created in the first place. Thanks for the comments guys and sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had two different activity_main files, and one of the files had a small bug in the XML. I don't know how that second activity was created in the first place.

[image]